# Get the IP address of a device in a local network by its MAC address

Tags: ios, objective-c, bonjour

Is there a way to find the IP address of a device in a LAN by its MAC address?

Could Apple's Bonjour be a possible solution?

Comment: You can have multiple IP addresses assigned to a single network interface, and thus to a single MAC. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I have a device with a MAC address and I need to know the IP address in a local network to establish a connection... the IP address is assigned dynamically by a DHCP server (router)